# With jfeinstein10's slidingmenu,how to create slide up menu

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I would like to use the sliding menu library to create a slide up menu which shows up in the bottom of the screen as you pull the bottom title bar up. Something like this..

[image: http://iglampixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/IMG_0024.png]

I am new to Android. Any idea how I could reuse the library to do this? Which class/function should be modified?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Short of modifying the entire library (_I am not aware of any that provides this OTB_), I am not sure there is any other option. But, you will have to do the modifications and when you come across a specific problem (_narrow_ it down), then SO can help. Right now, this is just too broad. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe modifying jfeinstein10's lib might take some time.
Consider the following well documented lib that fits your needs:

[Android Sliding Up Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Comment: Thanks Ranco.. I used the sliding up library you mentioned.        Sorry about the broad question.. I was not sure if I should use a new library for slide up as I am using the sliding menu library any case for the slide right menu...  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Ranco, Have a follow up question on the Android Sliding Up Panel library. I would like the panel thats pulled up to show up to a certain part of the screen and not full screen. 
For example, when you slide up- the pulled panel should be shown on the bottom 50% of the screen, while the actual content which was there should be shown for the top 50% of the screen. I tried the various functions in the library but was not able to find a way to do this.. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you will have to dive into the library's code and modify it,I haven't done it but I'll try to give it time asap

Comment: In case, anybody else is interested in sliding up partially , here it is - https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/9