# Android: How to create a 'SplitContainer' between two 'Views'

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-gesture

[image]

According to the screenshots I want to achieve the following ScreenUI (Android API >= 10):

You have a `GoogleMapsSupportFragement` and a `ListView`, which share the remaining height of the View (`height` is calculated at the application start, and application is only runnning in `PortraitMode`)

The behaviour of the `ListView` Container should be similar to the Android-Notification Menu, so user can swipe the List in and out, but the animation starts, if user releases the view (touch up).

So far, I implemented the two `LinearLayout` (`Map` and `ListView`) which are divided by the redline (`LinearLayout`). I managed, that the ListView is shown/hidden on click at the redline, but it`s looking odd if I hide the ListView, because the map is redrawn and leaves a black space..

**Question is:** What`s best way to implement (LinearLayout? Fragments?)? Do you know examples for the`onTouchBehaviour` (similar to open Notication Menu)?

Here's my implementation:

```
//function is triggered at click on the redline-button
private void toggleOverlayList(){

    //TEST CASE API >= 11 

    int mListHeight = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_list)).getLayoutParams().height;
    Log.i(DEBUG,"toggleOverlayList() -> currentHeight:" + mListHeight );

    if(mListHeight == 0){
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_wrapper)).getLayoutParams().height = mDisplayHeight;
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_list)).getLayoutParams().height = mDisplayHeight;
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_screen)).requestLayout();
    }
    else{
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_wrapper)).getLayoutParams().height = 2* mDisplayHeight;
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_list)).getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_screen)).requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/main_screen"
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/map_wrapper">
      <fragment
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_seperator"
    android:layout_height="20dp" >
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_list">

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1" >
   </ListView>

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library instead of implementing this by yourself.
take a look at my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584853/with-jfeinstein10s-slidingmenu-how-to-create-slide-up-menu/17585413#17585413). hope it helps.

Comment: good library! but i have to check if it´s possible to `divide` the main view, instead of overlapping the whole screen.